# NGINX Ingress Controller IP address not reachable

Tags: nginx

I have set up a [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) giving following result when querying with

```
kubectl -n ingress-controller get services
nginx-ingress-controller        NodePort    10.107.224.151   <none>        80:30003/TCP,443:30989/TCP   2m16s
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP   10.96.210.169    <none>        80/TCP                       2m16s
```

However, when trying to run this curl command:

```
curl https://10.107.224.151
```

I get no response, only a timeout error after a while.

What do I get wrong?

Comment: Port 80 is not HTTPS; it’s HTTP. And your output indicates port 80; HTTPS is port 443 which you do not have set. So my guess is if you run `curl http://10.107.224.151` you will get a response. Even slicker, you can simply check response headers using the `-I` option like this: `curl -I http://10.107.224.151`. I find that more useful than simply dumping a whole HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I tried the http-variant before I put up the question and it did not get an answer either. But you are saying that there should be an answer meaning that since the pod is up and running as a NodePort, it should be reachable. I still get: `$ curl http://10.101.62.45
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.101.62.45 port 80: Connection timed out`. Do you think this is a connection issue?